# How to reuse a list in c#?

Tags: c#, list

I declare a `List <T>` and a `List<List<T>>` before starting a loop. then some elements are being added to the `List <T>`. After a condition, I add the `List <T>` to the `List<List<T>>`. At this point I need to `Clear` the `List <T>` so I can use it again, but that also delete the elements from the `List<List<T>>`, which is something I don't want to happen, what should I do?

```
int counter;
List<List<T>> parent= new List<List<T>>();
List<T> child= new List<T>();
for (counter = 0; counter <= group.Count - 2; counter++)
{
    // some code here
    if ( /* condition */ )
    {
        child.Add(element);
        child.Add(element2);
        parent.Add(child);
        child.Clear();
    }
}
```

Note: I know that one of the solutions is to use `new List<T>();` inside the loop, but it is not an option for me.

Comment: Why is `new List<T>` not an option?

Comment: `new LisT<T>(); inside the loop, but it is not an option for me` - frankly, that's the ONLY option if you are goign to Clear the original lists. Also, since the 'child' list is reused in all iterations of the loop, you have to clear it to not mixup the sublists from different iterations. So either stop worrying too much or sto being afraid of creating too many  objects and just create a new child-list in each iteration, or stop using lists and use something else.. - I dont know what.

Comment: @KlausGütter: he already wrote `Note: I know that one of the solutions is to use new LisT<T>(); inside the loop, but it is not an option for me.` so such a note w/o explanation or some rationale to convice him - is pointless.

Comment: If it's not an option, then you are out of luck. `List<T>` is a reference type. When you added it to the outer list, you added a reference to the list that you constructed and filled. If you clear that list, the reference in the outer list will still refer to the same list, but it will be empty. Why wouldn't it "be an option" for you. It's the right way to do what you want to do

Answer (score 4):

You cannot reuse the child list. Lists are classes and therefore reference types. This means that you actually don't store the child list object itself in the parent list but a reference the unique child list you created. As a result, all positions of the list are pointing to the same unique child list.
You must create a new child list each time.

```
List<List<T>> parent = new List<List<T>>();
for (counter = 0; counter <= group.Count - 2; counter++)
{
    if (condition)
    {
        var child = new List<T>();
        child.Add(element);
        child.Add(element2);
        parent.Add(child);
    }
}
```

This can be visualized like this:

```
                      child list object
variable              +-----------+
+-------+             |           |
|child  o------------>|           |
+-------+             |           |
                      |           |
                      |           |
                      |           |
                      |           |
                      |           |
                      +-----------+
```

The result of reusing the list would be:

```
                       child list
                      +-----------+
parent list      +--->|           |
+--------+       |    |-----------|
|        |o----->|    |           |
|--------|       |    |-----------+
|        |o----->|    |           |
|--------|       |    +-----------+
|        |o----->|
|--------|       |
|        |o----->|
|--------|       |
|        |o------+
+--------+
```

Answer (score 2):

Since `= new List<T>()` is not an option for you, 
you can  call `ToList()` on the `child List` when adding it to the `parent List`.

```
parent.Add(child.ToList());
```

This will result into a new separate list being added to `parent`.
Afterwards, it's safe to clear the `child List`.

```
int counter;
List<List<T>> parent= new List<List<T>>();
List<T> child= new List<T>();
for (counter = 0; counter <= group.Count - 2; counter++)
{
    // some code here
    if (//condition)
    {
        child.Add(element);
        child.Add(element2);
        parent.Add(child.ToList());
        child.Clear();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly what I need, it works :)

Comment: Isn't this solution worse than using new List();? child.ToList() actually uses the new List() and copies the items by going through each item and copy it to the list. Thus this approach is inferior to simply go child = new List();

Comment: @Tartori I agree, but it is **the only way to meet OP's requirements** for not using `= new List<T>()`.

Comment: The OP assumes that the list behaves like a value type, i.e. that its content gets copied at `parent.Add(child)`. In that case it would make sense to reuse the list. But in reality it makes things worse. Therefore these requirements should be revised.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes I totally share your opinion on this.

Comment: You mean that `List<T>.ToList()` returns a new list, I always thought that it simply returned `this`. I know that `IEnumerable<T>.ToList()` creates a new list and does the copy, but that makes no sense for the List class. Unfortunately I'm not near a computer to test this.

Comment: @Flydog57 It really does create a new `List<T>`; also had to double-check on my pc to be convinced.

Comment: The reason for this is because it just uses the implementation of the `Enumerable` partial class. This implementation is never overwritten for the `List` class. Quite astounding I checked the source code for this information

Comment: This "new List is not an option" is an absurd requirement, only showing a misunderstanding of how lists actually work in c#. Leading an obvious beginner to think he can dispense with duplicating the list is hardly helpful, in my opinion. He will end up writing even worse code while thinking he solved his problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you actually want to avoid allocating a new list, then you must use another language. C# simply can't do what you ask it to do.

C# lists are [reference types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/reference-types). When you write `List<T> x = y;`, you just make `x` an alias of `y` (technically, you store a reference to `y` into `x`). You don't copy the actual list of elements referenced by `y` into `x`, only a reference to whatever `y` happens to hold at any given moment. If you change anything to `y`, `x` will simply reflect these changes. For instance, if you clear `y`, `x` will reference an empty list.

If you want to retain the state of `y` at the moment you assign `x`, you have to create a copy of `y` and have `x` reference that copy.

Then you have to decide [how deep that copy is](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/shallow-copy-and-deep-copy-in-c-sharp/).

For your list to be fully "reusable" (so that you could do every conceivable operation on it without affecting the list referenced by `x` in any way), you would require a costly and most likely useless deep copy.

If you simply want to be able to add or remove elements however you like, a shallow copy will be enough.

That copy process, shallow or not, will involve creating a new List instance at some point. This is simply how reference types work. You can't magic the copy away. Therefore, if some strange rule forbids you to create a new instance of `List<T>`, your problem has no solution.

Now if it's your clueless boss bullying you into some "good practice" that disallows the use of "new List", then sweeping the dirt under the rug might be an option, for instance:

- using `ToList` to surreptitiously duplicate the list.

  ```
    List<T> PleaseMyCluelessBoss (List<T> myNotToBeAllocatedList)
    {
        return myNotToBeAllocatedList.ToList();
    }
  ```
- using `GetRange` on the whole list (selecting all elements and copying them into a new list)

  ```
    List<T> PleaseMyCluelessBoss (List<T> myNotToBeAllocatedList)
    {
        return myNotToBeAllocatedList.GetRange(0, myNotToBeAllocatedList.Count);
    }
  ```

There are other, even more complicated ways of doing the same, but whatever convoluted workaround you use, a new list *will* be allocated, then the original list will be copied into it, and you'll end up doing the same thing as calling `parent.Add(new List<T>(child))`, which is arguably the simplest way of making a shallow copy of a list. Ah, but your requirement will be met and your boss will be pleased: no "new List" in sight.

Looking at your code snippet, the `child` list serves no other purpose than being populated, copied and emptied immediately, which is basically what a [list initializer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers) does, only in a more efficient way. The sensible approach would be to do away with it, if you ask me:

```
int counter;
List<List<T>> parent= new List<List<T>>();
// no need to allocate anything there
for (counter = 0; counter <= group.Count - 2; counter++)
{
    // some code here
    if ( /* condition */ )
    {
        // allocate your list on the spot and put it where it belongs
        parent.Add(new List<T> { element, element2 });
    }
}
```

Or if your "some code" happens to add elements to `child`, this version will dump whatever has been collected since the last addition into `parent`:

```
int counter;
List<List<T>> parent= new List<List<T>>();
List<T> child= new List<T>();
for (counter = 0; counter <= group.Count - 2; counter++)
{
    // some code possibly adding elements to child 

    if (/* condition */)
    {
        child.Add(element);
        child.Add(element2);
        parent.Add(child);

        // don't "reuse" the list, just "reuse" the reference to start with a brand new list
        child = new List<T>();
    }
}
```

Surely you have your reasons to do otherwise, but the example you give keeps me guessing as to why you would want to "reuse" this list in the first place...